# Sort list by property name AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a complex object that looks like:

```
   {
      'street35':[
          {'address154': 'name14'},
          {'address244': 'name2'}
      ],
      'street2':[
          {'address15': 'name1'},
          {'address234': 'name2'}
      ]
   }
```

I'm binding it to the html using the **(value, key) in object** attribute that angular.js provides. I want to order by the value in this case by the street name. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

JS:

```
   $scope.streetsObject = {
      'street35':[
          {'address154': 'name14'},
          {'address244': 'name2'}
      ],
      'street2':[
          {'address15': 'name1'},
          {'address234': 'name2'}
      ]
   }
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="street in streetsObject | orderBy">
    <span ng-repeat"name in street">
    </span>
</div>
```

The code supposes that you are using angular 1.3.0+.